# is spark cache() causing a collect() to the driver in this case?

Tags: apache-spark

need some help interpreting some error log from Spark. My understanding is that a cache shouldn't trigger all data to be sent to the driver. I have an abbreviated stacktrace that looks like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
  at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:205)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec.doExecuteBroadcast(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:136)
   ...
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.persist(Dataset.scala:2902)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.cache(Dataset.scala:2912)
   ...
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 16 tasks (1076.4 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1750)

   ...
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:938)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectIterator(SparkPlan.scala:304)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:76)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:73)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:97)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:72)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:72)
   ...
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
```

It looks like the cache kicked off a broadcast which then eventually calls a collect on an RDD which then triggers a "Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 16 tasks (1076.4 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)" error.

It is bit confusing to me why I am seeing this error -- what I've read about `.cache` is that it persists in the node and doesn't have to move all the data into the driver.

the code looks like this. we have a job which rolls up a series of events by a visit_id. it reads the events, projects some fields and then aggregates them like this:

```
  def aggregateRows: sql.DataFrame = {
    projected
      .orderBy("headerTimestamp")
      .groupBy(groupBys.head, groupBys.tail: _*)
      .agg(
        first("accountState", ignoreNulls = true).alias("accountState"),
        first("userId", ignoreNulls = true).alias("userId"),
        first("subaffiliateId", ignoreNulls = true).alias("subaffiliateId"),
        first("clientPlatform", ignoreNulls = true).alias("clientPlatform"),
        first("localTimestamp", ignoreNulls = true).alias("localTimestamp"),
        first("page", ignoreNulls = true).alias("firstPage")
      )
  }
```

(incidentally, I think this code isn't correct w/r/t to getting the 1st row because the groupBy apparently doesn't maintain ordering, but this is the code which I was running when I got this error)

Then we join this visits rollup on `user_id` like this (we create a temp view called "visits" using `createOrReplaceTempView` and spark sql):

```
  SELECT
    u.days_since_last_active,
    u.user_id,
    v.appName as app_name,
    v.clientPlatform as client_platform,
    v.countryCode as country_code,
    v.llChannel as ll_channel,
    v.llSource as ll_source,
    v.referralKey as referral_key,
    v.visitTimestamp as resurrection_time,
    v.subaffiliateId as subaffiliateId,
    v.visitDate as resurrection_date,
    v.accountState as account_state,
    v.ipAddress as ip_address,
    v.localTimestamp as resurrection_local_time,
    v.visitId as visit_id,
    v.firstPage as resurrection_page,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY u.days_since_last_active, u.user_id ORDER BY v.visitTimestamp) as rn
  FROM ubdm u
  LEFT OUTER JOIN visits v ON v.userId = u.user_id
    AND u.date = '$dateStr'
    AND (u.days_since_last_active > 30
      OR (u.days_since_signup > 30 AND u.days_since_last_active IS NULL))
```

we then call `cache` on the above and then write the dataframe as a tsv and parquet

```
val cached = generateDataFrame().cache()

writeParquet(cached.write, parquetPath)
writeTsv(cached.write, tsvPath)
```

the `.write` returns a `DataFrameWriter`. Finally, for parquet for instance, we call the following on the `DataFrameWriter`

```
  def writeParquet[A](df: DataFrameWriter[A], outputPath: String, saveMode: SaveMode = SaveMode.Overwrite): Unit = {
    df.mode(saveMode)
      .parquet(outputPath)
  }
```

Comment: `cache()` shouldn't be the reason for the error. Does it work if you remove it? And also, can you add your code?

Comment: Could you share your code ?

Answer (score 0):

As i understand it - everything works fine. And no, `cache` does not trigger `collect`.

As you remember - spark has `transformations` and `actions`. `Transformations` are triggered only by `actions`. `collect` is an action, that triggered calculation on `rdd` that has `cache` somewhere in between.

You get the error because you try to `collect` too much data (that does not fit into you driver node).

P.S. If you could share the code - that would be nice, btw.

Comment: i haven't shared all the code because it might be too much for anyone to read but I assure that there is no place where `collect` is called explicitly.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist In your code you do not perform any actions. There are only transformations. Please share code with actions (save somewhere, write to file, show, e.t.c)

Comment: sorry, just added them

Answer (score 0):

On Spark 2.3, `cache()` **does** trigger collecting broadcast data on the driver. This was a [bug (SPARK-23880)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23880) - it has been fixed in version 2.4.0.

As for transformations vs actions: some Spark transformations involve an additional action, e.g. `sortByKey` on RDDs. So dividing all Spark operations to either transformations or actions is a bit of an oversimplification.